# bluebird promise each not return the last result

Tags: promise, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I am using `promise.each` to loop through 2 db query using `bookshelfjs`, but roles is not giving me the result of this -> `roles[resource.get('name')] = role.get('name');`, but it give me the object from slect statement:

```
var promise = new Promise(
        function resolver(resolve, reject) {   
            var roles = {};
            Promise.each(user.relations.relates.models, function(relation){
                return Resource.forge({resourceId: relation.get('resourceId')}).fetch().then(function(resource){
                    return Role.forge({roleId: relation.get('roleId')}).fetch().then(function(role){
                        roles[resource.get('name')] = role.get('name');
                        return roles;
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        reject({"status":"error", "data": err});
                    });
                }).catch(function(err){
                    reject({"status":"error", "data": err});
                });
            }).then(function(roles){
              resolve(roles);
            });
        }
    );

    return promise;
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bluebird docs for `Promise.each()`:

> Resolves to the original array unmodified, this method is meant to be
>   used for side effects.

So, that means that when you do:

```
Promise.each(array).then(function(val) {
   // iteration finished here
   // val is the original array
});
```

That `val` will be the original array you passed in, not your `roles` object.

Because your `roles` object is in a higher scope, you can remove the parameter declared as `roles` in your `.then()` handler and just directly refer to the higher scoped `roles` variable.

You should also avoid the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) here and not create a new promise, but just return the one you already have.

You can do that like this:

```
var roles = {};
return Promise.each(user.relations.relates.models, function (relation) {
    return Resource.forge({resourceId: relation.get('resourceId')}).fetch().then(function (resource) {
        return Role.forge({roleId: relation.get('roleId')}).fetch().then(function (role) {
            roles[resource.get('name')] = role.get('name');
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // repackage how the error is presented into our own object
        throw ({"status": "error", "data": err});
    });
}).then(function () {
    // make the resolved value of the final promise be the roles object
    return roles;
});
```

The resolved value of this returned promise will be your `roles` object.

**Summary of Changes:**

1. Return the promise from `Promise.each()` rather than creating a new promise (no need to create a new promise here).
2. Let rejects propagate back up, no need to manually reject a higher level promise.
3. In the `.then()` handler for the `Promise.each()`, remove the declared parameter named `roles` since that conflicts with your higher scoped `roles` object.
4. Return `roles` in that `.then()` handler so it becomes the resolve value of the promise you are returning.
5. Remove the inner `.catch()` since the outer `.catch()` can do it's work also.
6. Change the `.catch()` to throw the repackaged error value.
7. Remove the inner `return roles;` since it is not needed.  The `roles` object is constantly available at a higher scope so there is no need to make it a resolved value of these inner promises (in fact, that may just create confusion to do so).

---

Possible performance optimization.  Since none of your results depend upon the prior results, it appears that maybe you could run all your async operations in parallel rather than in series in which case you could replace `Promise.each()` with `Promise.map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sorry, we changed our mind.

In 3.x we were supposed to make `.each` return the results rather than the original values but that broke the code for a lot of people so we changed it back and added a `mapSeries`.

Basically, use `.mapSeries` whenever you'd use `each` and care about the results, it does exactly what you'd expect. If you can run the items concurrently use `.map` though as it'll likely perform much better.

Comment: But he's just building an object of results, not making an array.  So, `.mapSeries()` doesn't seem like the right type of result.  He could use `Promise.reduce()` and just constantly be returning the same object that he's building up, but that's not really simpler than `Promise.each()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 you can mapSeries over keys and then place it back in an object and not reduce. Although OP is probably looking for `props`.

Comment: I thought about `Promise.props()`, but isn't the input is an array, not an object?  The case where the input is an array and the output is an object of collected results doesn't really have a prepackaged function in Bluebird to do as best I can see.